# Animate movement of React component from one to another

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to animate moving react component from one to another. For example take very simple, yet interesting card game: you may place any card to a deck, or take top card from the deck.

To make it work, I have 4 classes - `<Board>` which holds two `<Card Collection>`: "Deck" and "Hand" components. In constructor, they generate CardModel items and render them via `<Card>` component. `<CardCollection>` component has special `onCardClick` prop which takes callback function. In my case it's `onCardClick={/*this is equal to <Board>*/ this.transferCard("Hand")}`

`Board.transferCard` takes clicked CardModel from state of one component and pushes it to another.

The problem is animation - I want card to fly, preferably through center (optional!) from old place to new. I am able to place the newly created Card in "new place" to the same place as old component, but, since i jsut strated to learn React, I'm not sure where exactly I should start. Wrap in ReactCSSTransitionGroup? pass "animate: from{x,y} to{x,y}" property to `<CardCollection>`?

So the full question is what is the most generic, controllable and "react" way to animate this situation?

JSFiddle base question version: https://jsfiddle.net/fen1kz/6qxpzmm6/

JSFiddle first animation prototype version: https://jsfiddle.net/fen1kz/6qxpzmm6/1

I don't like `<this.state.animations.map...` here. Also the Animation component looks like an abomination for me, I'm not sure this is the good architecture style for React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main mistake I did is try to mix render function with animation. No! Render should not contain anything related to animation (preferably not even starter values), while all the animation should happen after render. The only thing that bothers me is that i still should have state of animations in CardCollection just to throw it into creation of Card

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fen1kz/6qxpzmm6/4/

```
      let animation;
      if (this.animations[cardModel.id] != void 0) {
        animation = this.animations[cardModel.id];
        this.animations[cardModel.id] = void 0;
      }
      ...
      return <Card 
               cardModel={cardModel} 
               onCardClick={onCardClick}
               animation={animation}
               position={this.getCardPosition(i)}
               index={i}
               key={cardModel.id}
               ref={cardModel.id} // prolly not needed
               />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a package I made called react-singular-component, which might actually do what you need.

The component allows you to render a component server times and by a given priority only the highest one will render. Mounting and uncounting the given component will cause the next highest priority to render instead with an animation moving and wrapping the component from its last place and size to the new one.

Here is the Github page: https://github.com/dor6/SingularComponent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -3):

Just an idea: You could try to use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for animation of moving some HTML element from one place to another. Once animation is complete there is a `complete` function property only then you could trigger your `onCardClick`.

Comment: I've updated examples section. Used Velocity.js, as you see - this is still unacceptable solution. Multiple cards are not working. Also, what concerning me, is that i'm manipulating dom without react knowing it. not sure if it's good